# How to redirect *some* pages using javascript in WP?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a function that is in Wordpress theme functions.php document, on an intranet website, which refreshes the page after a timeout. It works fine, but I need to have some pages where the refresh *will not* be active.

As I am not a js guy, I would appreciate some help here.  :-I

```
function inactive_page_redirect(){ ?>
  
<script>
//Using setTimeout to execute a function after 30 min.
setTimeout(function () {
   //Redirect with JavaScript
   window.location.href= 'http://wpr.wtsrb.local/';
}, 1800000); //30 min
</script>
  
<?php } 
  
add_action('wp_footer', 'inactive_page_redirect');
```

Thanks!

Comment: `if` conditions are pretty similar in most programming languages. You already know how to read the current URL with `window.location.href`.

Comment: @jabaa appreciated. Will try. :-)

Comment: I would first take a look at wordpress [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#visual-overview), then based on the template/page the users is currently on, i would use wordpress [conditional tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) to not/inject my javascript.